# app close suddenly when i try to pass a bitmap to another activity in android

Tags: android, bitmap, resize, bundle

i try to **pass bitmap** from first activity to second activity
it works correctly , but when i try to change bitmap size , **app closes suddenly**

```
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            double heightD = bitmap.getHeight() / 4.5;
            double widthD = bitmap.getWidth() / 4.5;
            int height = (int) heightD;
            int width = (int) widthD;
            bitmap = scaleDownBitmapImage(bitmap, width, height);
            bundle.putParcelable("key", bitmap);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CheckTokenImage.class);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(intent);
```

it works , but if i change **4.5** to **4.4 or lower** app crash and it stop suddenly!!
any help , please ?

Update : the "Unfortunately, MyApp has stopped" doesn't show , just it jump out, and i can open it from recently app list

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: post your Crash log.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: @VladMatvienko as i said "Unfortunately, MyApp has stopped." doesn't show , i update post , it just jumps out and no error shows

Comment: `as i said` you said that **after** my comment. Do you see any logs in logcat? It is very rare case when app crashes without exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, now I see the problem. You try to pass `Bitmap` through `Bundle`.
You should not do that since `Bundle` size is limited, and `Bitmap` is likely too large. You should avoid passing large data through `Bundle`.

Instead you can save your Bitmap to the file, and pass file path through Bundle, and open in from file path in receiver.
Or use static field somewhere.

Comment: @hassanmoradnezhad, obviously because it is still enough for smaller bitmap, but not enough for larger.

Comment: This is perfect! u saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

Place large bitmaps in bundle by encoding to string :

```
//quality [0... 100]
public static String encodeImage(Bitmap image, Bitmap.CompressFormat compressFormat, int quality) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    image.compress(compressFormat, quality, byteArrayOS);
    return Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOS.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
}

public static Bitmap decodeImage(String input) {
    byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decode(input, 0);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedBytes, 0, decodedBytes.length);
}
```

It may consume some performances.

You can also write bitmap to file in cache folder and place file's **path** String in bundle.